# Image in HTML hard coded or css?

Tags: html, css

How can I put an image in place of text "Submit" .. hard coded or css? what is better option.

```
 <ul>
     <li><span class="class1" onclick="func1()">Submit</span></li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: Is this a regular image? Why not use an image tag and a src generated by the server? Or will it change dynamically on the client?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add an image to your class:

```
<ul>
     <li><span class="class1" onclick="func1()"></span></li>
</ul>


.class1 {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
    background-image: url(myimage.png);
}
```

Comment: url(myimage.png) - how is that path known?

Comment: You point it to the respective path of where you intend to serve up the image.

Answer (score 0):

The alternative to what you have is, of course,

```
<a href="#" onclick="func1()"><img src="picture.png" /></a>
```

and you can style the `a` (or `img`) to your heart's content in your CSS